# How to use fgets() instead of fscanf() on stdin in C?

Tags: c, unix, stdin, fgets

I want to use fgets instead of fscanf to get stdin and send it to a child process via a pipe.  The code below works for sorting the lines in the file but replacing

```
fscanf(stdin, "%s", word)
```

with

```
fgets(word, 5000, stdin)
```

gives me the warning

```
warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
```

Otherwise the program seems to work.  Any ideas why I am getting the warning?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  pid_t sortPid;
  int status;
  FILE *writeToChild;
  char word[5000];
  int count = 1;

  int sortFds[2];
  pipe(sortFds);

  switch (sortPid = fork()) {
    case 0: //this is the child process
      close(sortFds[1]); //close the write end of the pipe
      dup(sortFds[0]);
      close(sortFds[0]);
      execl("/usr/bin/sort", "sort", (char *) 0);
      perror("execl of sort failed");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    case -1: //failure to fork case
      perror("Could not create child");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    default: //this is the parent process
      close(sortFds[0]); //close the read end of the pipe
      writeToChild = fdopen(sortFds[1], "w");
      break;
  }

  if (writeToChild != 0) { //do this if you are the parent
    while (fscanf(stdin, "%s", word) != EOF) {
      fprintf(writeToChild, "%s %d\n",  word, count);
    }   
  }  

  fclose(writeToChild);

  wait(&status);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fscanf returns an `int`, fgets a `char *`. Your comparision with EOF results in the warning for a `char *` since EOF is an `int`.

fgets returns NULL on EOF or error, so check for that.

Answer (score 2):

The prototype of [**fgets**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/?kw=fgets) is:

> char * fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream );

fgets will read the newline character into your string,so if you use it, part of your code may write as:

```
if (writeToChild != 0){
    while (fgets(word, sizeof(word), stdin) != NULL){
        count = strlen(word);
        word[--count] = '\0'; //discard the newline character 
        fprintf(writeToChild, "%s %d\n",  word, count);
    }
}
```